# Classification and HMM

Tags: hidden-markov-model

I have a classifier which assigns a behavioural class to segments of data such that the output emissions that result are a sequence of predicted animal behaviours such as:

Foraging ==> Foraging ==> Resting ==> Resting ==> Relocating

Inevitably, some behaviours will be misclassified for example the likelihood of finding a Relocating segment within a resting segment would be very low within the context of my work e.g:

Resting ==> Resting ==> Relocating ==> Resting ==> Resting

Therefore I would like to work towards reducing this type of error in the classified sequences.

My question is, would it be possible to train a hidden Markov model using the transition and emission probabilities of the 3 behaviours to 'smooth' such sequence errors such that:

Resting ==> Resting ==> Resting ==> Resting ==> Resting